# In edit mode, if I move a vertex the whole mesh is transformed

Tags: mesh

Not sure what I've done or pressed, but in edit mode if I select a vertex/edge/face the whole mesh is transformed when I grab, rotate, etc. Also if I add new mesh elements and scale for instance even unselected elements are scaling 
What have I pressed?

Thanks
John

Comment: maybe you've enabled the Proportional Editing option (blue circle icon on the horizontal menu bar of the 3D view)

Comment: There is no "mesh" mode. It's called edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

you have probably enabled proportional editing the hotkey should be 'O'   [image: 2.80][image: 2.79]

Comment: thanks that was spot on - As a relative new comer to blender I think the down side of the massive number of short cuts is its easy to accidentally enable stuff without realising - is there a general reset? like reloading the default state?

Comment: @Johnsta not that one that i know of.